# VBscript automation script stuck when IE modal popup appears

Tags: vbscript

I am using vbscript to automate an website operation using IE. 
At one place, clicking a button creates a modal popup. When the popup appears, the script does not execute further and sort of freezes.

I thought of executing a second script, but I am unable to activate the popup window. The popup dialog has title as "Proceed -- Webpage Dialog", and 2 buttons - Ok and Cancel. I'm using the below code to activate the pop up window and then click Ok on it. But I am unable to capture the window. Below is the code for second script.

**script2.vbs:**

```
WScript.Sleep 5000

Msgbox "Started 2nd script"

For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        If InStr(1, wnd.Document.Title, "Proceed", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set objIE = wnd
            MsgBox "Found Window"
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This does nothing, and I have no clue how to handle this popup. Any thoughts or workarounds for this, will be very helpful.

### **Update:**

Below is the code for the main script.

**script1.vbs:**

```
Dim url
url = "http://example.com"

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.AddressBar = True
objIE.StatusBar = False
objIE.MenuBar = True

WshShell.AppActivate ("Internet Explorer")
objIE.Navigate url

'''
'   Some code to perform website operations 
'
'

WshShell.Run "script2.vbs"

''The below line triggers the popup
Set btn = objIE.Document.GetElementById("grayBtn").GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(0)
btn.Click
```

Comment: That's what modal means...it will wait for the user to take action before it resumes execution.  Unfortunately, there don't seem to be many options in vbscript for creating a modeless dialog.  I would consider using powershell.

Comment: Yes. you're right. I just want to know, is it possible to handle the pop-up by starting one more script?

Comment: If you show the code that calls the other script, that might help us to see what's wrong.

Comment: Just before the click event which triggers the popup, I'm calling a second script, which has the above mentioned code. If you want the contents of the first script, I can update the code, but that just works fine until the pop up appears. I hope, I'm clear :)

Comment: You should provide all the relevant code and only the relevant code.  See this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: like roryap says, vbscript is not a good choice to do this kind of stuff, Ruby is far better and an ideal stepup from vbscript( did it myself), if you provide the real url I'm willing to show you how this kan be done in just a few lines of Ruby code

Comment: This is an internal web site and inaccessible outside the organization. Can you share some useful links which shows the same in Ruby.

Comment: @peter, I asked a separate question for this. Would appreciate your help on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040869/ie-automation-using-ruby-issue-with-modal-popup